# Embedding image at runtime in action script

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, embed

I have to create the image object using something like this

```
[Embed("/assets/images/Header.png")]  
public static var HeaderIcon:Class;
```

but now the string within embedd is dynamically brought from some xml
like `xmlObject.child("icon");` which I tried it like

```
[Embed(xmlObject.child('icon').toString())]  
public static var HeaderIcon:Class;
```

However it gives errors like

> invalid metadata

I am using the above code in action script(as is obvious)
Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: You either embed an image or you load it at runtime. "Embedding at runtime" is a contradiction in terms.

Comment: so how to load it at runtime and create a Class variable for that, as in the above case [Embed(xmlObject.child('icon').toString())]   public static var HeaderIcon:Class;

Comment: @veer7 Load assets at runtime using an Image class [or similar alternative] and specifying a URL to the image as the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the Loader class: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html

It's a bit more complicated than with embedded resources, but there are good examples in the documentation.

Comment: thank u Miguel. I couldn't get that as it was in espanol. I tried to edit the url  es_ES to en_US but that didn't work. Could you please check if u can provide that in en_US

Answer (score 0):

Class Name: -HeaderIconClass

//////////

```
package
{
    import spark.components.Image;

    internal dynamic class HeaderIconClass extends Image
    {
        public function HeaderIconClass()
        {
            super();
        }
    }
}
```

Inside your component or Application level: -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
               creationComplete="application1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            [Bindable]
            public var headerIcon:HeaderIconClass = new HeaderIconClass();

            //For your testing
            protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                imageID.source = headerIcon.source
            }

            protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                headerIcon.source = "@Embed('/assets/images/Header.png')";
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <mx:VBox x="100" y="100">
        <s:Button label="Show Image" click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>
        <s:Image id="imageID" width="50" height="50"/>
    </mx:VBox>
</s:Application>
```

If you want to use this you can save this in variable: -

```
private var imagePath:String = xmlObject.child('icon').toString();
```

and change below function as: -

```
protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    headerIcon.source = "@Embed('"+imagePath+"')";
}
```

Hope this may help .....

Comment: The problem is that the headerIcon has to be cast to Class type. Which was not possible for my program using the above code.